# Does the latest version of geth does not create geth.ipc?

Tags: go-ethereum, accounts

I have seen similar question about the geth.ipc file ([I can't find my geth.ipc](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/24946/i-cant-find-my-geth-ipc)), I am on Windows 7.

I am not able to see geth.ipc file after running geth as said in the other question thread, tough I am able to connect to geth in other instance of command window using (>geth  attach) without passing the path for geth.ipc, my question is the new version of geth does not create geth.ipc?

> geth attach ipc:MyPvtBlockChain1/geth.ipc

Executing the above command says

> Fatal:Unable to attach to remote geth: Invalid pipe address MyPvtBlockChain/geth.ipc

The problem is that I have created two private blockchains on my machine now. It is a problem to connect these two separate blockchains without the geth.ipc file. Both my `geth attach` command connect to same geth node instance and not separate blockchains I have created, I have checked it using `admin.nodeInfo` command and both windows point to the same geth node.

When I try to run geth on the another private blockchain like this, the `--ipcpath` is requried here, but as I do not have access to geth.ipc file there is no way I can run geth on the my second blockchain instance which would require the command below, which takes details of my second blockchain and run it on a seperate port number.

### Run Geth for first blockchain

> geth --datadir MyPvtBlockChainData1 --port 30303 --nodiscover --ipcpath MyPvtBlockChainData1/geth.ipc" --networkid 1234 console

### Run Geth for second blockchain

> geth --datadir MyPvtBlockChainData2 --port 30304 --nodiscover --ipcpath MyPvtBlockChainData2/geth.ipc" --networkid 1234 console

Comment: I'm not running geth on windows so I can't speak from experience but [does this help?](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/1597)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On Windows geth uses named pipes. The named pipes do not exists as a files in your filesystems but as object in the window's kernel.

All such objects are located in the path `\\.\pipe`. For example geth uses `geth.ipc` and the named pipe is at `\\.\pipe\geth.ipc`. On Windows geth you can only set the name and not the path `--ipcpath geth-demo.ipc`.

To run two instances you have to specify different names for each instance

> geth --datadir datadir1 --port 30303 --nodiscover --ipcpath geth-data1.ipc --networkid 1234 console
>
> geth --datadir datadir2 --port 30304 --nodiscover --ipcpath geth-data2.ipc --networkid 1234 console

Now you can connect to the first instance with

> `geth attach ipc:\\.\pipe\geth-data1.ipc`

And the second instance with

> `geth attach ipc:\\.\pipe\geth-data2.ipc`

Comment: This does not work  geth --datadir datadir1 --port 30303 --nodiscover --ipcpath geth-data1.ipc" --networkid 1234 console  trying to run that is just standing their and not running geth at all...

Comment: There was a " that should not be there.

Comment: Sorry, works like charm now :)