# Launch more than one node connected to Rinkeby from the same machine (change the port doesnt work)

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, mist, testnets, rinkeby

I would like to know if it is possible to launch more than one node connected to Rinkeby from the same machine through Geth and Mist.

In a local testnet, it is possible to do it changing the --port and --rpcport, but I am trying the same connecting to Rinkeby and I get the following error:

```
    Database closed                 
    Fatal: Error starting protocol stack: Access is denied.
```

I can launch another geth instance just if I disable the ipc-rpc (--icpdisable), but it is not the right solution since it is not possible to deploy Mist.

Comment: Did you change the datadir?

Comment: Yes, I changed it.

Comment: Are you using windows? Perhaps this will help https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/38032

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using docker. There are lots of network configuration options with docker (it is can be a bit confusing often getting all this right actually).

Try run the following two commands. They bind the ethereum nodes to different ports.

```
docker run --name ethereum-one \
           -p 8545:8545 -p 30303:30303 \
           ethereum/client-go --rinkeby



docker run --name ethereum-two \
           -p 8546:8545 -p 30304:30303 \
           ethereum/client-go --rinkeby
```

https://hub.docker.com/r/ethereum/client-go/ <- is the reference. I'm sorry I can't give more details, but I know it is possible with docker. Good luck.

(I hope this works for you)